# select from table with group by where date>date in mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

What I require is, show the first done_on_date for unique combination of machine_id and operation_id which will be done using group by function, again I would like to show done_on_date which has to be exactly done_on_date after the first selected done_on_date for the unique combination of machine_id and operation_id.

So far what I have tried is something like below.

```html
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM maintenance_entry_table 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT (done_on_date) AS done_on_date1, maintenance_entry_table.*
        FROM maintenance_entry_table $where 
        GROUP BY machine_id,operation_id) as groupedDate 
    ON maintenance_entry_table.machine_id = groupedDate.machine_id
        AND maintenance_entry_table.operation_id = groupedDate.operation_id 
        AND maintenance_entry_table.done_on_date > groupedDate.done_on_date1 
    group by machine_id, operation_id”;
```

$where is explicitly defined as where clause somewhere else.

But It doesn't seem to work. It brings up the same done_on_date instead of the one after that, for the unique combination of machine_id and operation_id. I am totally clueless.

further how it is being shown on html page is as given below.

```html
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['machine_id'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['operation_id'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['done_on_date'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['done_on_date1'] ."</td>"; //this brings up same date as 'done_on_date' whereas it should be the next date coming in row for the unique combination of machine_id and operation_id
echo "</tr>";
```

If i explain it further, its something like, let us say for example, you have 2 porsche cars defined as porsche_1 and porsche_2. Now, the porsche_1 is sent to mechanic for servicing 4 times in 1 year. Now let us assume the type of service mechanic performed is same called service_1. So, Service_1 first time done is 01/04/2017 for porsche_1. Service_1 second time done is 15/04/2017 for porsche_1. Service_1 third time done is 18/04/2017 for porsche_1 and Service_1 forth time done is 20/04/2017 for porsche_1. I would like these detail in a single row like below,

```html
car_name    service_name    done_date     done_date  
porsche_1     service_1,     01/04/2017    15/04/2017
porsche_1     service_1      15/04/2017    18/04/2017
porsche_1     service_1      18/04/2017    20/04/2018
porsche_1     service_1      20/04/2017   blank  //bcoz service not yet executed
```

Accordingly for other cars as well.

Hope this is clear enough now.

Comment: `SELECT * ... group by machine_id, operation_id` is asking for invalid data because you are misusing MySQL's GROUP BY feature..  Read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @SumanDey how to frame a query to get done_on_date and another done_on_date for the unique combination of machine_id and operation_id. At the last, cars explanation is self explanatory.

Comment: I mean it’s actually confusing AF

Comment: So you’re trying to make a vertical table horizontal in respect to the done dates or does every service specifically have two done dates that are nonsensically named?

Comment: @MasonStedman, example data is often nonsensical.

Comment: If a service was done 4 times for a user, which two dates do you want returned? The first and last? The last 2? Edit your question with this info rather than add a comment.

Comment: @sloan I was trying to get a clarification on what he was asking for as the example made no sense

Comment: @SloanThrasher cars example further explained please. Sorry all if I am by any means unable to express off what I am after. Hope this is clear now or ready to edit furhter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want all service dates for each car and service type. Since you didn't include the schema of your tables, 
I've written this with just the columns you've mentioned. Feel free to add any missing columns. I've also created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d31/5) 
that builds the table and runs the query below.

Instead of individual columns for the dates, they are in one column separated by commas. You can easily explode this column when displaying the 
values. If you create a separate column for each date, you will have to know the maximum number of dates and build a query with a join for each date.

```
SELECT
    a.`car_name`,
    a.`service_name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.`done_date` ORDER BY a.`done_date` ASC) as `Dates_Done`
FROM `maintenance_entry_table` a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        c.`car_name`,
        c.`service_name`,
        MIN(`done_date`) as `first_date`
    FROM `maintenance_entry_table` c
    GROUP BY c.`car_name`,c.`service_name`
    ) b
ON b.`first_date` < a.`done_date` AND b.`car_name` = a.`car_name` AND b.`service_name` = a.`service_name`
GROUP BY a.`car_name`,a.`service_name`
ORDER BY a.`car_name`,a.`service_name`;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d31/5/0)**:

```
|  car_name |   service_name |                       Dates_Done |
|-----------|----------------|----------------------------------|
|    benz_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-14,2017-05-24            |
| porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-04,2017-04-15,2017-07-12 |
| porsche_1 | replace_wipers | 2017-01-04                       |
| porsche_1 |     tire_check | 2017-01-04,2017-06-11            |
| porsche_2 |     oil_change | 2017-05-01,2017-08-20            |
```

---

**EDIT**

---

This should produce your example output, for each car and service and date, it will output the car, service, date and the next date of service:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d31/16)

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT
    a.`car_name`,
    a.`service_name`,
    a.`done_date`,
    coalesce(MIN(b.`done_date`),'') as `next_done_date`
FROM `maintenance_entry_table` a
LEFT JOIN `maintenance_entry_table` b
ON b.`done_date` > a.`done_date` AND 
    b.`car_name` = a.`car_name` AND 
    b.`service_name` = a.`service_name`
GROUP BY a.`car_name`,a.`service_name`,a.`done_date`
ORDER BY a.`car_name`,a.`service_name`,a.`done_date`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d31/16/0)**:

```
|  car_name |   service_name |  done_date | next_done_date |
|-----------|----------------|------------|----------------|
|    benz_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-14 |     2017-05-24 |
|    benz_1 |     oil_change | 2017-05-24 |                |
| porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-04 |     2017-04-15 |
| porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-04-15 |     2017-07-12 |
| porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-07-12 |                |
| porsche_1 | replace_wipers | 2017-01-04 |                |
| porsche_1 |     tire_check | 2017-01-04 |     2017-06-11 |
| porsche_1 |     tire_check | 2017-06-11 |                |
| porsche_2 |     oil_change | 2017-05-01 |     2017-08-20 |
| porsche_2 |     oil_change | 2017-08-20 |                |
```

---

**[Source Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d31/16/1)**:

```
| id |  car_name |   service_name |  done_date |
|----|-----------|----------------|------------|
|  1 | porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-04 |
|  2 | porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-04-15 |
|  3 | porsche_1 |     oil_change | 2017-07-12 |
|  4 |    benz_1 |     oil_change | 2017-01-14 |
|  5 |    benz_1 |     oil_change | 2017-05-24 |
|  6 | porsche_1 |     tire_check | 2017-01-04 |
|  7 | porsche_1 |     tire_check | 2017-06-11 |
|  8 | porsche_1 | replace_wipers | 2017-01-04 |
|  9 | porsche_2 |     oil_change | 2017-05-01 |
| 10 | porsche_2 |     oil_change | 2017-08-20 |
```

Comment: I'll try tomorrow for sure, but I am afraid as min(done_date) would always start for each row with minimum date whereas required is exactly as stated in the car example wherein first row first done_date and second done_date..........second done_date will become the first done_date for second row and so on.....sorry group by won't be required I guess inside the left join (select statement) as I would want for each car and their associated service types.

Comment: The join prevents what you say about the same car+service repeating with each date as 1st done_date. Unless that is what your want. The group by in the sub-query is how you get the earliest done_date for a specific car + service.If you really want to display as in your example output, then using this result you can do that easily in PHP.

Comment: See my updated answer. If you want the results in date_done order, simply change the *ORDER BY* clause and put ```a.date_done``` first.

Comment: Sorry to bother you , if you can spare some time, can you look at the following query I am struggling with.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531586/unable-to-read-data-from-socket-can-not-bind-to-address-in-php